# ¿Álguien sabe cómo filtrar con dt.filter de PrimeNG?

Tags: html, angular, filtro, primeng

Me explico, esta es la estructura de HTML que pinta unos botones que filtran con un evento Click que usa el dt.filter() de PrimeNG, uno de los apartados llamado "SIN PREVENTIVO" se tiene que encargar de mostrar lo mismo que el apartado "TODOS" pero sin ciertos elementos que son "PREVENTIVOS", de ahí su nombre... la cuestión es que me he peleado con la documentación y no encuentro nada para filtrar dichos elementos tipo (click)="dt.filter('preventivo', 'estado', 'Not contains'); o algo así... ojalá haya alguien que se haya ya peleado con él y haya resuelto el problema...

Este es el código:

`

```
<div class='row' style='justify-content: center;'>

    <div style="padding-top: 30px;" class='col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 text-center'>
        <div class='card cursor' (click)="dt.filter('', 'estado', 'contains');dt.filter('', 'prioridad', 'contains');" style='height: 50px; width: 100%; min-width: 95px;'>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px; font-size: 13px;" class='txtp'>TODOS</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 30px;" class='col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 text-center'>
        <div class='card cursor' (click)="dt.filter('', 'estado', 'contains');dt.filter('', 'prioridad', 'contains');" style='height: 50px; width: 100%; min-width: 95px;'>
            <p style="margin-top: 5px; font-size: 13px;" class='txtp'>SIN PREVENTIVO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 30px;" class='col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 text-center' >
        <div class='card cursor' (click)="dt.filter('urgente', 'prioridad', 'contains')" style='height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: #f5a623; min-width: 95px;'>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px; font-size: 13px;" class='txtp'>URGENTE</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 30px;" class='col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 text-center' >
        <div class='card cursor' (click)="dt.filter('preventivo', 'prioridad', 'contains')" style='height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: #50E3C2; min-width: 95px;'>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px; font-size: 13px;" class='txtp'>PREVENTIVO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 text-center' style="padding-top: 30px;" *ngFor="let a of provider.accesos">
        <div class='card cursor' (click)="dt.filter(a.nombre, 'estado', 'contains')" [style.background-color]="a.color" style='height: 50px; width:100%; min-width: 95px;'>
            <p style='margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;color: #001D19;'>{{a.total}}</p>
            <p style="margin: 0px; font-size: 13px;" class='txtp2'>{{a.nombre}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

`

Aquí os dejo una imagen de lo que se vería:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si creas tu propio método para filtrar ?

Comment: Tal vez FilterService te pueda ayudar [FilterService](https://primeng.org/filterservice)

Comment: @René lo probé pero no hace ni caso... como si no lo hubiera puesto...